# Move the draggable view to the corners of the other view using pan gesture in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to implement the video call screen like whats app. I am trying to drag the view of the receiver and based on dragging it should be moved to that position. for eg.if the user moves the receiver view to the bottom left or any othe side but it should place to the near corner of the main view(i.e sender view) but the  conditions are not working fine. the thing is it is exactly like the reciever screen moving in whatsapp video call page

```
@IBOutlet weak var sampleView: UIView!
var initialCenter = CGPoint()
var viewOrigin: CGPoint!
viewOrigin = sampleView.frame.origin
@IBAction func panView(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    //let endPoint = sender.translation(in: self.view)
    guard sender.view != nil else {return}
    let viewToDrag = sender.view!
    // Get the changes in the X and Y directions relative to
    // the superview's coordinate space.
    let endPoint = sender.translation(in: viewToDrag.superview)
    
    let velocity = sender.velocity(in: viewToDrag.superview)
    if sender.state == .began {
       // Save the view's original position.
       self.initialCenter = viewToDrag.center
    }
       // Update the position for the .began, .changed, and .ended states
    if sender.state != .cancelled {
       // Add the X and Y translation to the view's original position.
      let k: CGFloat = view.bounds.size.height / view.bounds.size.width
      let b = view.bounds.size.height

      if endPoint.y < k * endPoint.x && endPoint.y < -1 * k * endPoint.x + b {
          print("top edge")
          viewToDrag.center = CGPoint(x: viewToDrag.center.x + endPoint.x, y: viewToDrag.center.y + endPoint.y)
          sender.setTranslation(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), in: viewToDrag)
      } else if endPoint.y <= k * endPoint.x && endPoint.y >= -1 * k * endPoint.x + b {
          print("right edge")
          viewToDrag.center = CGPoint(x: viewToDrag.center.x + endPoint.x, y: viewToDrag.center.y + endPoint.y)
          sender.setTranslation(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), in: viewToDrag)
      } else if endPoint.y > k * endPoint.x && endPoint.y > -1 * k * endPoint.x + b {
          print("bottom edge")
          viewToDrag.center = CGPoint(x: viewToDrag.center.x + endPoint.x, y: viewToDrag.center.y + endPoint.y)
          sender.setTranslation(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), in: viewToDrag)
      } else if endPoint.y > k * endPoint.x && endPoint.y < -1 * k * endPoint.x + b {
          print("left edge")
          UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
              self.sampleView.frame.origin = self.viewOrigin
          })
          viewToDrag.center = CGPoint(x: viewToDrag.center.x + endPoint.x, y: viewToDrag.center.y + endPoint.y)
          sender.setTranslation(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), in: viewToDrag)
      }
                  

    }
    else {
       // On cancellation, return the piece to its original location.
       viewToDrag.center = initialCenter
    }
    
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you looking to do this? https://medium.com/@nathangitter/building-fluid-interfaces-ios-swift-9732bb934bf5 ... scroll down to **Interface #7: FaceTime PiP**

Comment: @DonMag - Thank you this article helped me.